# What does 'non minus stultum quam impium' mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation

I find this phrase on the Wikipedia page of [Julian of Eclanum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_of_Eclanum) and it is about the Anti-Pelaganism dogma (Julan was strongly against that dogma). From the words I think the dogma is "wicked stupidity of no little degree"? Is that correct.

What would be a good translation of the phrase?

Comment: It reads like: "it is no less stupid than it is wicked/ impious".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can translate this word by word:

- Non - *No*
- minus - *less*
- stultum - *stupid*
- quam - *than*
- impium - *wicked*

So it means: "No less stupid than wicked."

Who ever said Latin was difficult?

Comment: In perhaps a bit more idiomatic English, "It's every bit as stupid as it is wicked."

Comment: The translation "wicked" for "impius" strikes me as slightly simplistic, though obviously not wrong per se. But in the religious context offered here, it seems to me that aspect is not clear.

Comment: @Batavulus Indeed, “godless” may be a better term. Or just go with “impious” and hope whatever *that* means should be about the same thing that the Latin means ;-)

Comment: :-)  I had an insane but quite funny teacher once who claimed he had no idea what a “Heiland” (Dutch/German, take your pick) was, but that he thankfully knew what a Messiah/Messias was.